# Angular Test Simple Component -> NullInjectorError: No provider for xxx

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, angular6

I am trying to test simple component with no constructor and I am getting error

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for 'MyProviderName'
```

My component has one @Input, one @Output and one public method;

```
export class MyComponent {
  public prioritiesList: string[] = ["A", "B"];

  @Input() selectedPriority: string = "A";
  @Output() priorityChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new   EventEmitter<string>();

 public changePrioritySelection(priority: string) {
  this.selectedPriority = priority;
  this.priorityChanged.emit(priority);
 }
```

}

spec file:

```
beforeEach(() => {    
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent, SomePipe]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should be rendered properly', () => {
    expect(fixture).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

and pipe:

```
transform(value: any): string {
  return `${value} ${this.translationsProvider.getTranslated("translation.key")}`;
}
```

I can see no direct connection to 'MyProviderName' from this component.
Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: Could you share the code of `MyComponent` and `SomePipe` as well?

Comment: sure, I've updated the question

Comment: That's weird. There is no `MyProviderName ` in any of those files. So I assume, it is a cache problem or maybe the files are not saved properly. Can you make sure that files are saved properly and restart the test?